# Scala read first element of line separately

Tags: scala

I have the following input on a line:

1. number of elements in an array
2. elements of the array

For instance

```
3 1 2 3
```

or

```
5 10 20 30 40 50
```

Where `3` and `5` are the number of elements.

I would like to read this in Scala(first the number of elements, then the elements).

I tried doing something like this:

```
    val n = readInt
    val a = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

However, this doesn't read `n` correctly.

So what's the best way of reading this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of `split(" ")` and `splitAt(1)` to create a tuple containing the first element and the rest:

```
scala> val s = "3 1 2 3"
s: String = 3 1 2 3

scala> val (Array(nb), rest) = s.split(" ").map(_.toInt).splitAt(1)
nb: Int = 3
rest: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

(obviously you would replace `s` by `readLine` in your case).

Answer (score 2):

`readLine` is deprecated in latest scala. Try using `scala.io.StdIn.readLine` like

```
val a = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ").tail.map(_.toInt)
```

if user inputs `3 10 20 30`, then `a: Array[Int] = Array(10, 20, 30)`

Comment: Wouldn't you lose the `3` in `a`? (since you called `.tail` on the array returned by `split(" ")`)

Answer (score 1):

This maybe?

```
val a = readLine.split(" ").tail.map(_.toInt)
val n = a.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `List` that has a convenient extractor.

```
@ val s = "3 1 2 3"
s: String = "3 1 2 3"
@ val nb :: rest = s.split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList
nb: Int = 3
rest: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach to extract values from a collection, into head and rest of elements, for `val in = "3 1 2  3"`, as follows,

```
val Array(n, xs @_*) = in.split("\\W+").map(_.toInt)
```

which delivers

```
n: Int = 3
xs: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Here we split by alphanumeric values, convert them onto `Int` values and extract the head `n` from the rest tagged with `xs`.